# Regex to remove unwanted text in gene sequences

Tags: regex

I have gene sequences that can have actual string text in them I want to remove with regex.  I would like to try to remove the errant text in a generic way with regex.  I'd like to remove all characters up to 10 chars between any invalid characters. I am assuming that anything between invalid chars up to 10 chars apart is part of the invalid text.

example :

```
BADTEXTATTHEBEGINNINGATCATCGGCCCATGCATMOREBADTEXTINTHEMIDDLEGCGGGGATCGCCCCTTTAAAATHISISSOMETEXTATTHEENDIWANTREMOVED
```

Valid sequence characters are ATCG.  Can we create a regex to reduce the above string to
`GATCATCGGCCCATGCATGCGGGGATCGCCCCTTTAAAAT`?
I understand that the G at the beginning of this final sequence is the last character of the word BEGINNING, which is the "bad" text at the beginning of the string.  I realize with regex, it is impossible to identify words, so I am willing to live this limitation.  Same with the T at the end, which is the first letter of "THIS".

I've tried to do something with repeated capture groups that allow for a certain number of chars between bad characters, but I can't seem to make it work right.  Maybe someone can help me...
This regex does not quite work to capture everything.

```
([^ACTG].{1,10}[^ACTG])+
```

Comment: maybe you meant something like this `(?:[^ACTG](?:[A-Z]{0,10}[^ACTG])?)+` See https://regex101.com/r/E94PAB/1 but this can always have overlap as A-Z can match valid characters.

Comment: @Thefourthbird - Almost.  I'd like to remove all characters up to 10 chars between any invalid characters.  I am assuming that anything between invalid chars up to 10 chars apart is part of the invalid text.  I've updated my post.

Comment: What you're trying to do is pretty hacky and will never even come close to producing an acceptable result on any arbitrary string. There simply are countless false positives as well as false negatives. Even if you use a dictionary of words, it's still not guaranteed. For example, "CAT" can either be a word or it can be part of the sequence. It's impossible (even for a human) to tell which one it is unless there's additional context.

Comment: @MikePone Mabye you can optionally repeat it `[^ACTG](?:[A-Z]{0,10}[^ACTG])*`  https://regex101.com/r/xZtIgw/1

Comment: Why is turning "obviously corrupt data" into "still corrupt data but it's less obvious" a useful thing to want to do?

Comment: @jhnc - It's called a best effort to automate a cleaning process...  Too many different texts to just match all of them.

Comment: @jhnc - you are certainly welcome to present an idea that removes all corrupt data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial string:

```
BADTEXTATTHEBEGINNINGATCATCGGCCCATGCATMOREBADTEXTINTHEMIDDLEGCGGGGATCGCCCCTTTAAAATHISISSOMETEXTATTHEENDIWANTREMOVED
```

String after replacing non-ACGT:

```
-A-T--TATT----G-----GATCATCGGCCCATGCAT-----A-T--T--T--------GCGGGGATCGCCCCTTTAAAAT---------T--TATT-------A-T-------
```

For this sample, a run of up to four ACGT characters can appear in the unwanted text. Examining other samples may give a sensible upper bound.

Perhaps "starts and ends with invalid character and contains no long runs of valid characters" is a better measure to use than "1 to 10 characters, starting and ending with invalid character"?

A regex for this is:

```
[^ACGT]((?![ACGT]{5,}).)*[^ACGT]
```

and matches:

```
BADTEXTATTHEBEGINNIN
MOREBADTEXTINTHEMIDDLE
HISISSOMETEXTATTHEENDIWANTREMOVED
```